# Display all the values of a table row in a Jquery Alert

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a table, with 3 columns. the last column is a link when i click on that link i need the values of the particular row to be displayed as an alert.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            id
            </th>
        <th>
            name
        </th>
          <th> 
            Occupation
        </th>
        <th>
            click the link
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var i in Model.allHuman)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(mo => i.id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(mo => i.name)
        </td>
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(mo => i.occupation)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='' id='ppl' name='ppl' class='humanclass'> display </a>
        </td>
```

When the user clicks on the link, an alert will be displayed with the content of that particuar row. The content should have the format `ID` followed by `NAME` and `OCCUPATION`.

JQuery method :

```
  $(function () {
        $('.humanclass').click(function () {
            alert( ?????????? );   // How to display ID, NAME and OCCUPATION of the ROW          
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of possible solutions : add `data` attribute to link like this:

```
<a href='' id='ppl' name='ppl' class='humanclass' data-id='@(i.id)' data-name='@(i.name)' data-occupation='@(i.occupation)' "> display </a>
```

and get it in jquery function

```
$(function () {
    $('.humanclass').click(function () {
        alert($(this).data("id"), $(this).data("name"), $(this).data("occupation"));  
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah I know, just trying to help :)

Comment: @naveen , may be you right but I do not claim that is the best solution :)

Comment: yours is the best way to go, if the same data aint already present in the table. thats all i meant friend. and i got a little sad that because the other answerer is a 11 point member he did not get any upvotes. mea culpa :)

Comment: In the alert, the ID value is getting displayed, but NAME and OCCUPATION aren't. Any clue ?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use the [jQuery parent function](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get the context of the current row that you clicked.

```
$('.humanclass').click(function () {
    var rowContext = $(this).parent('tr');
    var id = $("td:nth-child(0)", rowContext).val();
    var name = $("td:nth-child(1)", rowContext).val();
    var occupation = $("td:nth-child(2)", rowContext).val();
    alert(id+' '+name+' '+occupation);
});
```